# I'm getting performance slow for DoFilter Class AT Springboot version 2.6.6, any solution to improve?

Tags: java, performance-testing

Currently I'm working on API for Performance test,and getting the response time slow as trace with Dynatrace showing that slowness on doFilter >> BaseFilter>>Inflater.inflateBytesBytes. Currently we using spring version 2.6.6.

Any solution can i made to enhancement for improve the performance of my API. One more question did i can edit the Springboot java class code?

Comment: If the user's browser can decompress (request header) you can send compressed content which is/should be faster. However the compression costs too. Static content could be kept compressed. Also things like JPEG need not be compressed. So do a bit of network traffic analysis.

Comment: Thank you for that information @JoopEggen . Can u  show more details the method of compress the header or for content body?